# Webpack plugin change content with ast

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

**Problem**

Hi, I'm trying to write a plugin and use ast for parsing the file. But I can not make changes to code. For example this code does not change div to label. What is correct way to change ast?

```
    apply(compiler) {
      compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('MyPlugin', (factory) => {
        factory.hooks.parser.for('javascript/auto').tap('MyPlugin', (parser, options) => {
          parser.hooks.program.tap('MyPlugin', (ast, comments) => {

            if (parser.state &&
                parser.state.module &&
                parser.state.module.resource.indexOf('node_modules') === -1) {

            if (parser.state.module.resource.endsWith('tsx')) {
                var g = ast.body.filter(n=> n.type === 'ExportNamedDeclaration');

            for (let a of g) {
              var decl = a.declaration.declarations;

              if (decl && decl[0]) {
                decl[0].init.body.body[0].argument.arguments[0].raw = 'label';
                decl[0].init.body.body[0].argument.arguments[0].value = 'label';
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
}`
```

I just need to change div to label in return block or add data-attr to div. I do not want to use regular expressions and replace all file content, I want to make it with ast.
MyComponent.tsx can be as following:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as style from './MyComponent.css';

export const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={style['test']}>bla bla</div>
  );
};
```

May be somebody can provide small example to change something with abstract syntax tree in webpack plugin.

Comment: You probably need to return the modified ast.
You can checkout DefinePlugin to check how it modifies code: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/DefinePlugin.js?source=cc

Comment: What does the module you are testing this on look like?

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: felixmosh, thank you for reply, but I can not find in DefinePlugin, that they are modifying ast

Comment: Try adding UseStrictPlugin: [UseStrictPlugin.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/fde018300aa52262c384e937c408d5dd97d62951/lib/UseStrictPlugin.js#L15)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and pointed to in the webpack code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659421/change-source-code-of-a-module-via-ast-from-a-webpack-4-plugin), webpack ignores attempts to change the parser AST within a tap.

Plugins are expected to use the ast as a read-only map to build new dependencies in the [dependency graph](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/dependency-graph/). (This is less fragile about ordering and parallel executions as multiple plugins can add to the dependency graph without invalidating each other by changing the reference AST.)

Based on the [i18n-lang](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/i18n-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/index.js) and Define Plugins, an example of using the ast to build a dependency for your transformation could look like:

```
"use strict";
const pluginName = 'MyPlugin';
const NullFactory = require('webpack/lib/NullFactory');
const ConstDependency = require("webpack/lib/dependencies/ConstDependency");

class MyPlugin {

    apply(compiler) {

        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
            "MyPlugin",
            (compilation, { normalModuleFactory }) => {
                compilation.dependencyFactories.set(ConstDependency, new NullFactory());
                compilation.dependencyTemplates.set(
                    ConstDependency,
                    new ConstDependency.Template()
                );
            });


        compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('MyPlugin', (factory) => {
            factory.hooks.parser.for('javascript/auto').tap('MyPlugin', (parser, options) => {
                parser.hooks.program.tap('MyPlugin', (ast, comments) => {

                    if (parser.state &&
                        parser.state.module &&
                        parser.state.module.resource.indexOf('node_modules') === -1) {

                        if (parser.state.module.resource.endsWith('tsx')) {
                            var g = ast.body.map(n => {
                                try {
                                    let {expression:{left:{property:{name:my}}, right:{body:{body:[{argument:{arguments:[div]}}]}}}} = n
                                    return my == 'MyComponent' && div.value == 'div' ? div: false 
                                } catch(e) {
                                  return false;
                                }
                            }).filter(e=>e);
                            for (let div of g) {
                                let dep = new ConstDependency(JSON.stringify('label'), div.range);
                                    dep.loc = div.loc;
                                    parser.state.current.addDependency(dep);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

module.exports= MyPlugin;
```

Where the `ast` provided by parser may vary quite a bit with different loaders and changes to the input.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Comment: how sad, that AST is read-only :(